# keep installer applications up to date

Tags: applications, install

I have a folder with apps to deploy. But I would like these to be up to date. Anyone have any idea how to keep these applications up to date?

I can't use the MAS (mac app store?) because they are applications to deploy and not my applications. I use imagr to deploy my macOS images and it will look for the applications it needs to install in a folder and install them. (vscode and firefox do not exist in the mac app store...).

Comment: What do you mean?  Can't you just use the MAS to keep them updated?  Your quesiton is missing some info, see [ask] for good tips on asking questions.

Comment: No, I can't use the MAS (mac app store?) because they are applications to deploy and not my applications. I use imagr to deploy my macOS images and it will look for the applications it needs to install in a folder and install them. (vscode and firefox do not exist in the mac app store...)

Answer (score 1):

It‘s a rather broad question because the specific method depends on the applications in question. What I would do in such a situation is to script the download/update for all these applications via AppleScript, Shell Scripting or similar and run this updater either regularly from launchd or automatically whenever I create an image.